# Running logic tests on iOS 8/9 with Xcode 8 fails for libraries and frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on evaluating logic tests using Xcode 8 Beta 6 for an Objective-C Cocoa Touch static library. The deployment target is iOS 8.0, and everything works fine with Xcode 7.3.1. Xcode 8, however, tells me that `xctest` cannot be run. It reports this error:

> **iPhone 6 cannot run xctest.**
>
> iPhone 6 runs iOS 8.4, which is lower than xctest’s minimum deployment target. Change your project’s minimum deployment target or upgrade iPhone 6’s version of iOS.

In case that description is unclear, here is a screenshot of what happens when I use ⌘U to launch the tests:

[image: Xcode 8 failure]

The only way I can get the tests to run is to use the iOS 10 simulator. This is happening in an El Capitan 10.11.6 VM where I have only Xcode 8 Beta 6 installed. The simulators were installed using Xcode 8 Beta 5; I updated to Xcode 8 Beta 6 when it was released.

I tried creating a new Cocoa Touch framework project from scratch with its deployment target set to iOS 8.0. The result of trying to run the logic tests is the same as with my static library project. If I make a new single-window application and set its deployment target to iOS 8.0, then there are no problems executing the logic tests.

The example framework that I created is available here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2940479/MyFramework.zip

To reproduce the problem, open the framework in Xcode 8 and set the configuration to something other than an iOS 10 simulator version.

Is there something that can be tweaked in the Xcode project so that the logic tests to be run with versions of the simulator older than iOS 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that this was a [bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/27747702) in the Xcode 8 betas. With the 8.0 GM seed, logic tests work correctly in the iOS 9 simulator. However, there appears to be a [new bug](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4967778771533824) with running logic tests using the iOS 8 simulator.